# Cannot call show_frame function in tkinter outise of its class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

With the code below (that I took from `sentdex`) I am trying to raise the `PageOne` window when the correct password ("123") is inserted in the first page. However, I get the error:

`TypeError: show_frame() missing is 1 required positional argument: 'cont'`.

Isn't `PageOne` the argument?

Why is it not working? Could you also please explain what the "controller" variable does?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class Root(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        
        
        
        self.entry=tk.Entry(self, width = 35)
        self.entry.insert(0, 'Enter password')
        self.entry.config(fg = "grey")      
        # entry.bind('<FocusIn>', self.EntryFieldClicked)
        # entry.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: self.SubmitPass()))       
        self.entry.place(relx=.5, rely=.3,anchor = tk.CENTER)
        button=tk.Button( self,text="Show Password", width = 20,command = self.ShowPass).place(relx=.5, rely=.4,anchor = tk.CENTER)
        button=tk.Button(self,text="Submit",width = 20, command=self.SubmitPass).place(relx=.5, rely=.5,anchor = tk.CENTER)
        self.entry.config(fg = "grey")      
        self.entry.bind('<FocusIn>', self.EntryFieldClicked)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: self.SubmitPass ))
        label=tk.Label(self,text="Log in to continue")
        label.pack()
        
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

    def EntryFieldClicked(self,event):
            if self.entry.get() == 'Enter password':
               self.entry.delete(0, tk.END) 
               self.entry.insert(0, '')
               self.entry.config(fg = 'black', show = "*")

                

         
         
    def ShowPass(self):
            self.entry.config(fg = 'black', show = "")
            
            
            
    def SubmitPass(self):
           global  Password  
           Password = self.entry.get()
           if Password == "123":
               Root.show_frame(PageOne)
               
               
        
        

        


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.controller = controller

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()
        


app = Root()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
Root.show_frame(PageOne)
```

You are calling the method on the class rather than the instance, so the first argument is passes to the `self` parameter.

Your class needs to keep a reference to the controller, so that you can call the method via the controller.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ...

    def SubmitPass(self):
           global  Password  
           Password = self.entry.get()
           if Password == "123":
               self.controller.show_frame(PageOne)
```